# Compress a file with todays date

Tags: windows, dos, rar, winrar

I want to compress a file with name ASCOnnect200_V5.0.0.0_09_Dec_11.zip. I it possible with winrar/rar?

The file name ASCOnnect200_V5.0.0.0_ will be always constant and the date part will be in the format dd-mmm-yy.

Answer (score 1):

In cmd:

```
rar.exe a -ag+YYYYMMDD arc {FolderName}
```

The answer is in this forum :)